# Dealing cards in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function to deal out cards from a deck in javascript but when I create a parameter for future object properties in my deal function it returns the property as undefined. Why is this happening?

```
//Creates the deck
var deck = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 52) + 1;
var Ace = 1;
var Face = 10;
if (deck % 13 == 1) {
deck = Ace;
} else if (deck % 13 === 11 || deck % 13 === 12 || deck % 13 === 0) {
    deck = Face;
} else if (deck % 13 === 2) {
    deck = 2;
} else if (deck % 13 === 3) {
    deck = 3;
} else if (deck % 13 === 4) {
    deck = 4;
} else if (deck % 13 === 5) {
    deck = 5;
} else if (deck % 13 === 6) {
    deck = 6;
} else if (deck % 13 === 7) {
    deck = 7;
} else if (deck % 13 === 8) {
    deck = 8;
} else if (deck % 13 === 9) {
    deck = 9;
} else {
    deck = 10;
}
//Creates the player as an object
function Player(pcard1) {
    pcard1 = pcard1;
}
//Deals a random card out of the deck
var deal = function (pob) {
    pob = deck;
};
deal(Player.pcard1);
alert(Player.pcard1);
```

Comment: what do you mean by Player.pcard1.... it's worth posting full code..

Comment: This is the full code as of now, Player is the object and pcard1 is the Player's 1st card as a property.

Comment: where did you declare Player object?...in any way see my answer

Comment: You should read up on OO JavaScript. You are not doing it right.

Comment: Also use a swicth or an object, there is no need for all of the else ifs.

Comment: Pinkpanther, I'm using constructor notation to create my object, it's commented in the code.
Epascarello, I know that this could be shortened this is just a rough draft to get the base working.

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question, but i'm trying to understand what you need. You want to build a full deck representation, and than having a function for random extraction of a card from it?

Comment: @user2449973 you are correct :) now it's better to answer your own question for future visitors

Comment: @sixFingers No question is stupid. That's somewhat correct but the deck isn't going to be a constant, meaning that it's going to be one number that is constantly changing and I'm going to call on that number multiple times, but it will be different because it has changed.

Comment: @pinkpanther but that function won't allow me to assign the deal variable to different object properties, I only posted that to show you that the object was declared correctly.

Comment: Uhm, okay, but i can't think of a deck as a number (instead, an array of them). Let's admit it's a number, by obeying to the statistics of a deck, i guess it should mimick the behaviour of extracting a random value between 1 and 13 from 1 of 4 identically built cards list.. or i miss something?

Comment: @sixFingers it does do just that. Just think of it pulling out from an array of 52 numbers randomly, without declaring the array.

Comment: Okay, almost there, no probs with your approach. But, you should then keep track of extracted cards, or you wouldn't?

Comment: @sixFingers I will, I'll only allow a certain amount of duplicates to be dealt. I'm just trying to fix this right now.

Comment: @user2449973 when you use `Players.pcard1=deck` in your code(from your second link) you're at least initializing once...but `deal(pob)` will only modify local variable pob....that will not help modify object property cuz you'r not passing reference....that.... if you're not how to do this edit your question to exactly describe your problem with some more details...that way you can get good responses(perhaps by geeks) in the stack

Comment: @pinkpanther When I call the deal function with 'Player.pcard1' as the parameter isn't it initializing?

Comment: @user2449973 Yes, that will not be initialized only the current value of `Player.pcard1` will be passed to the variable `bob`...I have made a possible answer I will post if you want

Comment: @pinkpanther I thought the point of function parameters was to run the function with the code in it's place?
Yeah sure, if you think it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through some comments, some initial notes. I guess you miss some foundation about Javascript workings:

1. Player is a function, and that's a good starting point. But you then try to access a member of it. This is possible only after you instantiate a new object from the function, using it as a *constructor*:

   ```
   var player = new Player(card_value);
   player.pcard1; // this is the public member of a Player instance
   ```
2. Deal function should either return a value, or follow the aforementioned guideline;
3. It's unclear (although both are correct) why you use the "function FunctionName" and then "var FunctionName = function" approach.

That said, you can skip completely the long if/else block, substituting it with a more structured approach:

```
var Ace = 1;
var Face = 10;
var symbols = [Ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Face, Face, Face];
var deal = function() {
    var card = Math.random() * 51;
    return symbols[Math.floor(card % 12)];
}

var Player = function(card_value) {
    this.card = card_value;
}

var card_value = deal();
var player = new Player(card_value);
alert(player.card);
```

You can then assign a new card to the player with a simple:

```
player.card = deal();
```

And remember that you can attach any member you like to player:

```
player.name = "Rambo";
```

Comment: When I use "function Player" I am creating an object using constructor notation. You can read about it here, http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp under 
Using an Object Constructor.

Comment: Actually, what I posted _is_ constructor notation. Follow the example you posted (it's completed by the following part, "Creating JavaScript Object Instances"). See how it is used here (taken from your link): http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_create_object2

Comment: Thanks for explaining that to me, but if what you said is true why doesn't this work? http://jsfiddle.net/da5Tf/2/

Comment: @user2449973 you are using `Player = new Object(pcard1);
Player.pcard1 = pcard1;` but no where you have declared `pcard1` and initialized them before invoking them.... pcard1 and Player.pcard1 are not same in this context

Comment: But I'm declaring pcard 1 in that second "Player.pcard2 = pcard1;"

Comment: Oh, well. I get you now. You're completely misunderstanding JS foundations (don't get me wrong). You are trying to modify members and variables by reference. Are you coming from background in a different language? I may help with some more theoretical explanation. I'm fixing your fiddle with a working version of the code.

Comment: No, this is my first language sad to say. I am really rusty though.
Thanks for fixing it, hopefully I'll understand it when I see it.

Comment: @sixFingers that's what I've been telling

Comment: @pinkpanther sorry, dont won't to get in the way, but I suspect (haven't tested it yet) that you too miss something about JS. What's the point in having Player accessed _into_ a function with name "Player"? Haven't tested it yet, but this is surely not clarifying for user2449973.

Comment: @user2449973 i intended no offense :) I lack something but we lack different things sorry :) I have only told about the misunderstanding of that reference thing...not other than that

Comment: That's great, but with this there isn't a way to add more object properties to our already created objects or deal a new card to that property by calling that function.

Comment: @pinkpanther hey, didn't want to be rough at all :)

Comment: This comment sections is getting into forum-length, anyway: _any_ object allow for direct declaration of new members. So you can freely do player.member (where member is a name at your choice) after you instantiate (var player = new Player()) it. If you want to deal a new card, go with player.card = deal().

Comment: @sixFingers I don't understand how your fiddle works, but I understand it well enough to edit it to my liking so it will do. Thank you.

Comment: Ask anything you don't understand, probably this will be a separate question, related to general JS i guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By passing `Player.pcard1` you will only pass the current value of the variable to `bob` parameter, whatever you do on `bob` doesn't apply on `Player.pcard1`.

You should either write different functions for different parameters.

```
//Creates the player as an object
function Player(pcard1) {
    Player.pcard1 = pcard1;
}
//Deals a random card out of the deck
var deal = function () {
    Player.pcard1 = deck;
};
var deal2=function(){
    Player.id="hello";   
}
deal();
deal2();
alert(Player.pcard1);
alert(Player.id);
```

(or)

Write functions returning values:

```
function getDeckValue(){
        return deck;
 }
 function getID(){
        return "1234";
  }
 Player.pcard1=getDeckValue();
 Player.id=getID();
```

(Or)

Use much flexible concepts of `javascrit` pointed out by @sixFingers, define a class instantiate it write member functions etc.
    In this way you can just access like `Player.variable` etc..

Excellent tutrial (I mean it) on javascript by jquery developer: [Advanced Javascript](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/)  . It touches all oop concepts you want and discusses many features of javascript which you cannot find on w3schools.

**EDIT:** Working code of second example

```
    //Creates the deck
var deck = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 52) + 1;
var Ace = 1;
var Face = 10;
if (deck % 13 == 1) {
    deck = Ace;
} else if (deck % 13 === 11 || deck % 13 === 12 || deck % 13 === 0) {
    deck = Face;
} else if (deck % 13 === 2) {
    deck = 2;
} else if (deck % 13 === 3) {
    deck = 3;
} else if (deck % 13 === 4) {
    deck = 4;
} else if (deck % 13 === 5) {
    deck = 5;
} else if (deck % 13 === 6) {
    deck = 6;
} else if (deck % 13 === 7) {
    deck = 7;
} else if (deck % 13 === 8) {
    deck = 8;
} else if (deck % 13 === 9) {
    deck = 9;
} else {
    deck = 10;
}
//Creates the player as an object
function Player(pcard1){
   Player.pcard1=pcard1;   
}
function getDeckValue(){
        return deck;
 }
 function getID(){
        return "1234";
  }
 Player.pcard1=getDeckValue();
 Player.id=getID();

alert(Player.pcard1);
alert(Player.id);
```

Comment: Your first example kind of defeats the purpose of declaring a function if you have to keep making new functions don't you think?
And your second example doesn't assign any values to anything at all.

Comment: @user2449973 they are useful if they are wrapped in a class and you want to do some caluclations before acutally asigning them.... I have only shown that you can do this way.....but did you try my second example....it's working I will edit to post full code

Comment: @user2449973 you have asked to initialize different properties of `Player` but you did it wrongly in your code so I just gave it as an example that's it...you may do this for whatever properties you want....and you otherwise why not just do `Player.pcard1=deck` and `Player.someotherproperty=someotherassign`.... it works